# How to change background color of the active link in Angular js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

My html

```
<li data-ng-click="sortCategory('demographics')">Demographics</li>
<li data-ng-click="sortCategory('historical')">Historical</li>
<li data-ng-click="sortCategory('experimental')">Experimental</li>
```

I tried

```
<li data-ng-click="sortCategory('socialmedia'); select(item)" data-ng-class="{active: isActive(item)}">Social Media</li>

$scope.isActive = function (item) 
     {
return $scope.isActive(item);
     }
```

css (less)

```
li{
&.active {
  background:#0088cc;
}
}
```

It is not working...

Comment: Show the `select` method code and `isActive` method too.

Comment: [`data-ng-click="sortCategory = 'demographics'" ng-class="{active: sortCategory == 'demographics'}"`](http://jsbin.com/AMOVOSo/1/) would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully agree with Yoshi you can store the category in a scope variable when calling the sortCategory function and use this to check if a categrory is active or not. A working piece of code could be :

```
 $scope.category = 'demographics'; //Your default category
 $scope.sortCategory = function (category) {
   $scope.category = category; //Update the category
   ....
 }

 $scope.isActive = function (category) {
   //Check if category of a given <li> is equal to the current category
   return $scope.category === category;
 }
```

and a template markup that s look like

```
<li data-ng-click="sortCategory('demographics')" ng-class="{'active' : isActive('demographics')}">Demographics</li>
<li data-ng-click="sortCategory('historical')" ng-class="{'active' : isActive('historical')}">Historical</li>
```

You can find a live example here http://jsfiddle.net/sWKL5/2/